# Adding to a table then removing and adding again

Tags: react-native

## Good evening, I am developing a React native application...when I add a date to my table it is added correctly. When I remove it, it is also removed correctly, but when I add the same date **(23 and 30)** again it is not added to the table. but it is well selected in terms of the calendar. What am I forgetting?

- 
- 
- My code is available here: https://sharemycode.io/c/10cc31f

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please add only the relevant code as text to the question. Use a [mre]. Thanks & check out [ask] when you can.

Comment: The code link does not work. Please post your code as text.